# How to compose EAN128 in iReport barcode component?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, gs1-128

I hava a problem with barcode in ireport. I use ireport 3.7.4 with berbecue and barcode4j library.

I want to put into the EAN128 barcode following data:

253 application Identifier (Global Document Type Identifier) value 24.1 (document type) + 2076764 (document id)

414 application Identifier (Global Location Number) value 2095

91 application Identifier (Company internal information) value 20110101.

I used component barcode4j and barbecue, unfortunately without effect.
Both like barbecue and Barcode4j component doesn't recognize 253 and 414 application identifiers.
Could anybody explain me why I'm wrong and write a correct code expression.

Answer (score 1):

From [Barcode4J EAN-128](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/symbol-ean-128.html) document:

> The allowed data types are "n" (numeric), "an" (alpha-numeric), "d"
>   (date) and "cd" (check digit).

I'm not sure whether you can put a dot in the data.

To locate the source of the error, try adding one part of the barcode data at a time.